# Symfony - Save pdf file to upload directory with PsPdfBundle

Tags: symfony, pdf

I'm using the basic code from bundle to generate pdf and the browser-output works. (Controller)

```
public function fileAction($name, Request $request)
{
  $format = $this->get('request')->get('_format');      
  $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
  $entity = $em->getRepository('TestBundle:Kunden')->find($name);

  return $this->render(sprintf('TestBundle:Kunden:file.%s.twig', $format), array(
    'name' => $name,
    'entity' => $entity,
  ));
```

I want to save the file in upload folder, so I tried the code I found in documentation or other posts. (Controller)

```
 public function pdfAction($name)
{
  $format = $this->get('request')->get('_format');                  
  $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
  $entity = $em->getRepository('TestBundle:Kunden')->find($name);
  $facade = $this->get('ps_pdf.facade');
  $response = new Response();                           

  $this->render(sprintf('TestBundle:Kunden:file.%s.twig', $format), array('entity' => $entity,'name' => $name,), $response);

  $xml = $response->getContent();
  $content = $facade->render($xml);

  return new Response($content, 200, array('content-type' => 'application/pdf'));
}
```

I know that I missed something, but I don't know where I can define the path or filename. How could I save the generated pdf from fileAction() in upload folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are doing there is just generating a pdf file and returning it as a response / download response.
Saving a file to an upload directory is another task. I'd recommend you using a file abstraction layer for that, e.g. "[Gaufrette](https://github.com/KnpLabs/Gaufrette)" or "[Flysystem](https://github.com/1up-lab/OneupFlysystemBundle)"
Can't post a whole example here because it would be too long including all the config stuff, but in the end you would have something like:

```
 $filesystem->write('myFile', $content);
```

Hope this helps, 
++.

Comment: I used Gaufrette to save my pdf and it works. I generate the new file with the html-Template of the pdf-file and the pdf-preview with the pdf-Template. Not exactly what I want, because I wanted to generate the file from the pdf-Template. But thanks a lot - it's the best solution up to now.

Comment: Glad I could help. What's the difference between your html-Template and pdf-Template ? Aren't they both twig templates ? I don't know the bundle you're using, maybe I am missing something.

Comment: they are both twig templates, for the preview-pdf-Template the markup is like this: <pdf><dynamic-page></dynamic-page></pdf>. I use https://github.com/psliwa/PdfBundle